# Flutter - how add svg image?

Tags: flutter, svg

[image]
The following UnimplementedError was thrown in parseSvgElement:
The  element is not implemented in this library.

Style elements are not supported by this library and the requested SVG may not render as intended.

If possible, ensure the SVG uses inline styles and/or attributes (which are supported), or use a preprocessing utility such as svgcleaner to inline the styles for you.
2

Picture key: AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#e5679(), name: "assets/image/foodigo.svg", colorFilter: null, theme: SvgTheme(currentColor: Color(0xff000000), fontSize: 14.0, xHeight: 7.0))

Answer (score 0):

Not all SVG features are supported by `flutter_svg` package, as stated [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg#out-of-scopenon-goals).

You can try to use an online tool to "clean up" your SVG file (search for "SVG clean/optimize") or you can use one of the tools suggested in the same link above (like [usvg](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/resvg/tree/master/usvg)).

I would suggest `usvg` if you have a lot of files to process.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use flutter svg provider package for that : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg_provider